# How to fetch all the songs from folder from sd card

Tags: android

By using `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, I am getting all the audio files stored in card. But I want to fetch only contents of folder `MUSIC`.

How to fetch all the songs from `MUSIC` folder from SD card?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your post to include the specific question from the title. I removed statements that are do not offer more to the question. I also formatted your code samples with ` - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit to provide any additional details such as what else you have tried. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch audio from a specific folder using the code below

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " !=" + 0
        + " AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE '" + path
        + "/YourFolderNameHere/%'";
```

just replace YourFolderNameHere with MUSIC or whichever folder you need